# Is there a way to set the content type of Outputstream in AWS Lambda?

Tags: scala, aws-lambda, outputstream, aws-java-sdk

How can I use `OutputStream` to return content formatted as CSV? Something similar to this (except in Java/Scala):

`Response.ContentType = "application/CSV";`

The method signature for the lambda is:

```
  override def handleRequest(inputStream: InputStream, outputStream: OutputStream, context: Context): Unit = {
```

Right now I'm returning this:

```
outputStream.write(csvResult.toString.getBytes())
```

But the output is not formatted as CSV. Is there a way to set this property with `OutputStream`?

Comment: How are you interacting with the Lambda?  It sounds like you're assuming an HTTP stream and the Lambda by itself doesn't "talk" HTTP.  Do you have an API gateway in the front of the Lambda?

Comment: Yeah there's an API gateway that calls the Lambda

Comment: This will be something you set at the API Gateway level, not Lamda.  Take a look at [this article](https://kennbrodhagen.net/2016/01/31/how-to-return-html-from-aws-api-gateway-lambda/) which returns HTML but could be changed for your needs.